# Como limitar longitud de caracteres y rellenar con espacios en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola que tal quisiera saber como se le puede hacer en SQL SERVER limitar la longitud del carácter en este caso es a 24 caracteres pero si la longitud es menor a 24 que se acomplete con espacios.

Comment: No sé si te entiendo muy bien, pero me parece que lo que buscas es  un tipo de dato  `CHAR(24)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo en tu caso lo que haría seria concatenar dos cadenas y sacar de la derecha los 24 caracteres.
La primera cadena con espacios vacíos y la segunda con el valor que ocupo.

Al usar la función RIGHT te regresara de la derecha la cantidad de caracteres que tu especifiques.

```
RIGHT('                        ' + @cadena, 24)
```

Ejemplo

```
SELECT RIGHT('                        ' + '1', 24 ) PAD, LEN(RIGHT('                        ' + '1', 23 )) Longitud UNION 
SELECT RIGHT('                        ' + '12', 24 ) PAD, LEN(RIGHT('                        ' + '12', 24 )) Longitud UNION 
SELECT RIGHT('                        ' + '123', 24 ) PAD, LEN(RIGHT('                        ' + '123', 24 )) Longitud UNION 
SELECT RIGHT('                        ' + '1234', 24 ) PAD, LEN(RIGHT('                        ' + '1234', 24 )) Longitud UNION 
SELECT RIGHT('                        ' + '12345', 24 ) PAD, LEN(RIGHT('                        ' + '12345', 24 )) Longitud
```

Resultado

```
PAD                      Longitud
------------------------ -----------
                       1 24
                      12 24
                     123 24
                    1234 24
                   12345 24

(5 rows affected)
```